# Discord.py как удалить голосовой канал по его id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime
from datetime import date

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print('------')
    

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.event
async def weekstart(ctx):
    global id_vc
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    user = ctx.author
    id_vc = []
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Для того чтобы приянть учатие в нем используйте реакцию ниже',
                    colour=discord.Color.purple())
    ad = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Через 12 часов будет завершен сбор игроков',
                    colour=discord.Color.green())
    noend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description='Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан',
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    adnoend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description='Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан,для завершения эвента воспользуйтесь командой >weekstop',
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    mes = await user.send(embed=ad) 
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
      
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # 24 часов это 86400 секунд
    await message.clear_reaction('✅')
    ev = await ctx.send(embed=noend) 
    ev1 = await user.send(embed=adnoend)
    vc = await guild.create_voice_channel("gaming", overwrites=None, category=None, reason=None)
    id_vc.append(vc.id)
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.event
async def weekstop(ctx): 
    global id_vc
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    today = date.today()
    user = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await ctx.message.delete()
    end = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": завершён',
                    description='Всем спасибо за участие!Канал будет полностью очищен через 5 секунд!',
                    colour=discord.Color.red())
    en = await ctx.send(embed=end)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await channel.purge(limit=100)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    dataevent = discord.Embed(title=f'Последний эвент был:',
                    description= f"{today}",
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    ev = await ctx.send(embed=dataevent)
    adend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": завершён',
                    description='Эвент был успешно завершен!',
                    colour=discord.Color.red())

    
    
bot.run('token')
```

как удалять голосовой канал Discord если его id находиться в массиве глобальной переменной(id_vc = [])
ID берется из команды(>weekstart)
и передается в (>weekstop)

Comment: Ну, у вас в массиве объекты класса `VoiceChannel`, поэтому можно по нему просто пройтись через `for in` и к каждому применить [.delete()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_voice_channel#discord.VoiceChannel.delete).

Comment: @ГеннадийП ,огромнейшее спасибо!